# What algorithms are applicable to solve a inequality constraint Quadratic Optimization?

Tags: convex-analysis, quadratics, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose that we have a quadratic optimization problem 
$$(QP) \qquad \min \lbrace\frac{1}{2}x^TQX+ q^TX\rbrace $$
       s.t.
$$AX=a;$$
$$BX\le b;$$
$$X \ge 0;$$
where $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ symmetric and semi-positive definite, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m_1 \times n}$, $B\in \mathbb{R}^{m_2 \times n}$ and $m_1 \le n$ and  $m_2 \le n$.

What type of algorithm is appropriate to solve a medium-size instance of this problem?
I know for this type of QP, inequality constraint QP, two classes of solution algorithms exist; the active-set method and the interior point method. I am wondering if you can offer a source that introduces an appropriate and easy-to-understand algorithm for solving this QP with real application.

Comment: scipy, cvx, etc. Have you searched the internet ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by medium size, whether $Q$ is sparse, how many constraints you have etc. Possible choices may be interior point methods, active set, various proximal point algorithms such as the alternating directions method of multipliers (ADMM),  proximal gradient algorithms, semi-smooth Newton methods. There are numerous software you can easily use to solve such problems; @dohmatob pointed out to a few. Are you interested in understanding how algorithms work, or just use them?

Comment: Thank you@PantelisSopasakis!

Comment: Thank you @PantelisSopasakis!  We have a short model with 10 constraints. I searched in Google scholar and I found the active set and interior point methods as the most popular algorithms to solve QP. For the optimization, I would use CPLEX, but the problem is that CPLEX is not very powerful to solve QP in contrast of LP model. We are looking for an algorithm that can bid by CPLEX!